# When were the last autonomous indigenous American settlements conquered by the Spanish?

Tags: colonial-america, spanish-empire

We are generally taught about when Cortez and his allies in Tlaxcala defeated the Triple Alliance (Aztec) in 1521 and Francisco Pizarro in Peru in 1533. I also know Francisco de Montejo established Merida in the Maya region in 1542. But just because you conquer a capital doesn't mean you have administrative control over the whole territory. For example, I recently read on Wikipedia that [Nojpetén](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nojpet%C3%A9n) was the last autonomous Maya settlement when it was finally defeated 176 years later in 1697.

So what other regions that were claimed by the Spanish Empire in the Americas were finally conquered and forced under administrative control of the Spanish after 1542?

Note: Thank you to the commenters for help focusing this question. I've now re-written to make it more specific.

Comment: [Comancheria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comancheria) held out until after the U.S. Civil War. The Apache held out into the 1880's when Geronimo was finally captured. Where have you looked, and not looked, for your research?

Comment: ... of course it wasn't the Spanish who conquered it either, but the Americans. There were likely rather a lot of places that never saw a Spaniard. I'm curious how the author wants those places considered.

Comment: there are still isolated tribes in the Amazon. Not large, ok, but never conquered or officially contacted.

Comment: I am focusing specifically on Spanish Empire because I am more aware of all the "Indian Wars" of the 19th century US that had to happen before they were conquered.

Comment: I tried to make the question a little more specific.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conquest_of_the_Desert  1870, Argentinians conquered Patagonia. A large region never fully controlled by the Spanish empire.

Comment: Oh, good find. Also, Occupation of Araucanía from 1861–1883 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occupation_of_Araucan%C3%ADa

Comment: @Rozgonyi: All of both Comancheria and Apacheria were still Spanish claimed as late as 1790: [Map](https://www.worldatlas.com/r/w960-q80/upload/4d/1d/4c/shutterstock-2141774803.jpg) [Link](https://www.worldatlas.com/geography/the-former-spanish-colonies.html)

Answer (score -1):

Below is a list compiled based on input from commenters. I'm focusing on conflicts between indigenous groups and the Spanish (or subsequent states on colonial Spanish territories). Since "uncontacted" peoples in the Amazon aren't really in conflict with states (aside from possibly logging and oil industry), I'm not including them.

- 1572 - [Incas finally
  defeated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_conquest_of_the_Inca_Empire)
- 1697 - Nojpetén (Maya in modern Guatemala)
- 1844 - [Comancheria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comancheria) treaty with
  Texas
- 1883 - Araucanía (Mapuche in modern southern Chile)
- 1884 -
  Patagonia and Pampas (Mapuche and other groups in modern Argentina)
- 1886 - Apache defeated by what was then the United States